# comand to convert closed single quote to single quote in unix

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk, sed

i have tab sereated file.giving one scenario. 
contain Record `’RAZ’`.here it is on close single quote   i want to globally replace it with single quote `'RAZ'` on the same time
if close single quote is in middle of some word i don't want to replace.

Eg:

```
NAME|SUB
`RAZ` |Rockpor`t
```

i tried below command

```
sed -i "s/\’/'/g"  Test.txt
```

output :

```
'RAZ'|Rockpor't
```

Desired output should be :

```
'RAZ'|Rockpor`t
```

Please advise.

Comment: You are not using the same quotes in the text of your question (’ U+0060) than in the example data (` U+2019).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

your input file, say /tmp/abc.txt looks like

```
#cat /tmp/abc.txt
`ABC`|REsaff`t|`rest`
`PQR`|sasdasd`y|d`souza
```

Now, run this command

```
cat /tmp/abc.txt | sed s?\|?\\n\|?g | sed s?^\`?\'?g | sed s?\`\$?\'?g | sed s?^\|\`?\|\'?g | tr '\n' '#' | sed s?#\|?\|?g | tr '#' '\n'
```

What the command does is, it segregates all the tab values , if the value of the tab starts and ends with `, it replaces with ', then again merges all the tabs together.

Desired output:

```
'ABC'|REsaff`t|'rest'
'PQR'|sasdasd`y|d`souza
```

This solution will work with any number of tabs. The character ` will be replaced in all the tabs if the character resides at the start or at the end of the tab.

Note: The delimeter I have used here is `#` to segregate the newlines, you can use any accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This perl command will do it for you

```
perl -pe "s/`(?![a-z])|(?<![a-z])`/'/ig"
```

It replaces all backticks that are either not preceded or not followed by a letter

#### output

```
NAME|SUB
'RAZ' |Rockpor`t
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
perl -pe 's/(^|\W)`(.*?)`($|\W)/$1\x27$2\x27$3/g'
```

expanded

```
perl -pe '
    $q = "\x27";  # a single quote
    s{
        (^|\W)    # start of line or a non-word char
        `         # the open quote
        (.*?)     # some non-quote characters
        `         # the close quote
        ($|\W)    # end of line or a non-word char
    }{$1$q$2$q$3}gx
'
```

Demo

```
perl -pe '$q="\x27"; s/(^|\W)`(.*?)`($|\W)/$1$q$2$q$3/g' <<'END'
`foo`|I have James` hat|doesn`t
END
```

```
'foo'|I have James` hat|doesn`t
```

Answer (score -1):

use the below code.hope it helps.

```
 sed 's/`/'"'"'/;s/`/'"'"'/' test.txt
```

i used " to escape the single quote function.refer the below screenshot.graditude

[image]